# Passing focus from parent to children (as well as siblings)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a search bar (the parent) that has 3 child components - location dropdown, calender(date picker) and duration dropdown. By default the location is selected to wherever the user's location is. I want a change of focus to date picker where the calendar dropdown is opened automatically after there's an interaction with the first dropdown (location dropdown) and same applies from the second input to the third input. How can I go about doing this?

[image]

Parent:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Icon, Btn } from '@appearhere/bloom';

import Title from '../Title';
import LocationDropdown from '../LocationDropdown';
import AppearDateCalendar from '../AppearDateCalendar';
import DurationDropdown from '../DurationDropdown';

import css from './SegmentationBar.css';

import i18n from 'utils/i18n/i18n';

const t = i18n.withPrefix('client.apps.static.screens.home.header.segmentation');

type Props = {
  onLocationDropdownChange: Function,
  onDateChange: Function,
  onDurationChange: Function,
  onSubmit: Function,
  onMobileSearchClick: Function,
  fullSupport: boolean,
};

export default class SegmentationBar extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const {
      onLocationDropdownChange,
      onDateChange,
      onDurationChange,
      onSubmit,
      fullSupport,
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={css.container}>
        <Title />
        {fullSupport && (
          <div className={css.barWrapper}>
            <div className={css.segmentationBar}>
              <LocationDropdown onDropdownChange={onLocationDropdownChange} />
              <AppearDateCalendar onDateChange={onDateChange} />
              <DurationDropdown onDropdownChange={onDurationChange} />
            </div>
            <div className={css.submitButton} onClick={onSubmit}>
              <Icon name="search" />
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Children:

1st dropdown:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import i18n, { getCurrentLocale } from 'utils/i18n/i18n';

import { Icon } from '@appearhere/bloom';

import locationOrder from './locationOrder.json';
import locations from './locations.json';

import css from './LocationDropdown.css';

const t = i18n.withPrefix('client.apps.static.screens.home.header.segmentation.location');

type Props = {
  onDropdownChange: Function,
};

type Location = {
  key: string,
  name: string,
  country: string,
  placeId: string,
  searchString: string,
  priority: number,
};

class LocationDropdown extends Component<Props> {
  componentDidMount() {
    const selectedCity = this.findCitiesForCountry(locationOrder[getCurrentLocale()][0])[0];
    this.props.onDropdownChange(selectedCity.searchString, selectedCity.placeId);
  }

  citySorting = (a: Location, b: Location): number => {
    if (a.priority > b.priority) return 1;
    if (a.priority < b.priority) return -1;
    if (a.name >= b.name) return 1;
    return -1;
  };

  findCitiesForCountry = (countryKey: string): Array<Location> =>
    locations
      .filter((location: Location): boolean => location.country === countryKey)
      .sort(this.citySorting);

  handleDropdownChange = (event: SyntheticInputEvent<EventTarget>) => {
    const city = locations.find(
      (location: Location): boolean => location.key === event.target.value,
    );
    this.props.onDropdownChange(city.searchString, city.placeId);
  };

  renderSelectOptions = (countryKey: string): React.Node => {
    const cities = this.findCitiesForCountry(countryKey);
    return cities.map((city: Location): React.Node => (
      <option key={city.key} value={city.key}>
        {city.name}
      </option>
    ));
  };

  renderSelectOptionGroups = (): React.Node =>
    locationOrder[getCurrentLocale()].map((countryKey: string): React.Node => (
      <optgroup key={countryKey} label={t(countryKey)}>
        {this.renderSelectOptions(countryKey)}
      </optgroup>
    ));

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={css.LocationDropdown}>
        <div className={css.searchIcon}>
          <Icon name="search" />
        </div>
        <select role="listbox" className={css.locationSelect} onChange={this.handleDropdownChange}>
          {this.renderSelectOptionGroups()}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

2nd input:
Calendar:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import i18n from 'utils/i18n/i18n';

import { DayPicker } from '@appearhere/bloom';
import moment from 'utils/moment/moment';
import cx from 'classnames';

import css from './AppearDateCalendar.css';

const t = i18n.withPrefix('client.apps.static.screens.home.header.segmentation.calendar');

type Props = {
  onDateChange: Function,
};

type State = {
  calendarOpen: boolean,
  month: moment,
  day: ?moment,
};

export default class AppearDateCalendar extends Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    calendarOpen: false,
    month: moment(),
    day: undefined,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside);
  }

  handleClickOutside = (event: SyntheticMouseEvent<EventTarget>) => {
    const currentNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
    if (currentNode && !currentNode.contains(event.target)) {
      this.setState({ calendarOpen: false });
    }
  };

  handleCalendarClick = () => {
    this.setState({ calendarOpen: !this.state.calendarOpen });
  };

  handleMonthChange = (_event: any, newMonth: moment) => {
    this.setState({ month: newMonth });
  };

  handleDaySelect = (_event, day: moment) => {
    this.props.onDateChange(day);
    this.setState({ day, calendarOpen: false });
  };

  dateDisplayText = (): string => {
    if (this.state.day) return this.state.day.format('Do MMM, YY');
    return t('choose_date');
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={cx(css.appearDateCalendar, this.state.calendarOpen ? css.focused : '')}>
        <div onClick={this.handleCalendarClick}>
          <h5 className={css.heading}>{t('heading')}</h5>
          <p className={css.dateText}>{this.dateDisplayText()}</p>
        </div>
        {this.state.calendarOpen && (
          <div className={css.calendarDropdown}>
            <DayPicker
              month={this.state.month}
              onInteraction={this.handleDaySelect}
              onMonthChange={this.handleMonthChange}
            />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

3rd dropdown:
Duration:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import i18n from 'utils/i18n/i18n';

import css from './DurationDropdown.css';

import durations from './durations.json';

const t = i18n.withPrefix('client.apps.static.screens.home.header.segmentation.duration');

type Props = {
  onDropdownChange: Function,
};

type Duration = {
  name: string,
  maxDuration: number,
  highValue: boolean,
};

export default class DurationDropdown extends Component<Props> {
  handleDropdownChange = (event: SyntheticInputEvent<EventTarget>) => {
    const durationIndex = event.target.value;
    const duration = durations[durationIndex];
    this.props.onDropdownChange(duration.maxDuration, duration);
  };

  renderDurationOptions = (): React.Node =>
    durations.map((duration: Duration, index: number): React.Node => (
      <option key={duration.name} value={index}>
        {t(duration.name)}
      </option>
    ));

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={css.durationDropdown}>
        <h5 className={css.heading}>{t('heading')}</h5>
        <select role="listbox" className={css.durationSelect} onChange={this.handleDropdownChange}>
          <optgroup label={t('booking_duration')}>{this.renderDurationOptions()}</optgroup>
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read about React refs: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

You can create a `ref` per input, and pass it from your parent to the 3 children, and use `ref.current.focus()` in your dropdown handlers.